# PHP MySQL select based on range across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, select, range

I have a table setup similar to the below:

```
CREATE table TABLE_prices
(
PRICE_ID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
RANGE1_START int,
RANGE1_END int,
RANGE1_PRICE decimal(10,2),
RANGE2_START int,
RANGE2_END int,
RANGE2_PRICE decimal(10,2),    
RANGE3_START int,
RANGE3_END int,
RANGE3_PRICE decimal(10,2)
);
```

If I have a value (100 as an example), is there a way to build a select statement to get the RANGE#_PRICE based on which range the value falls in?

My instinct is that I'm probably going to have to extract the range data from MySQL and the iterate through it in PHP but I didn't know if there was a way to cut right to it with MySQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can do it in single statement:

```
$price = 100;

$sql = "
(
  SELECT 1 as range, price_id, range1_start as range_start, range1_end as range_end FROM table_prices WHERE range1_start >= $price AND range1_end <= $price
) UNION
(
  SELECT 2 as range, price_id, range2_start as range_start, range2_end as range_end FROM table_prices WHERE range2_start >= $price AND range2_end <= $price
) UNION
(
  SELECT 3 as range, price_id, range3_start as range_start, range3_end as range_end FROM table_prices WHERE range3_start >= $price AND range3_end <= $price
)";
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm basically trying to determine price for something based on the quantity.  So for example, RANGE1_START = 1 RANGE1_END = 10, RANGE2_START = 11 RANGE2_END = 20, etc.  So if the user selects a quantity of 15, I need to get RANGE2_PRICE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ugly solution:

```
SELECT
  PRICE_ID,
  COALESCE(
            CASE WHEN @value BETWEEN RANGE1_START AND RANGE1_END THEN RANGE1_PRICE END,
            CASE WHEN @value BETWEEN RANGE2_START AND RANGE2_END THEN RANGE2_PRICE END,
            CASE WHEN @value BETWEEN RANGE3_START AND RANGE3_END THEN RANGE3_PRICE END
          ) Price
FROM TABLE_prices
```

Comment: what if price is between range1, and range2 as well? :(

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Only first. But i assume the ranges can't intersect. No logic.